# Why does this error appear?

Tags: python

I suspect the static method tag is not detected or something.

```
>class Employee:
>   @staticmethod
>       def dayIsWorkday(day):
>           if day.weekday() == 5 or day.weekday() == 6:
>                 return False
>           return True
>
>
>import datetime
>my_date = datetime.date(2018, 12, 5)
>
>print(Employee.dayIsWorkday(my_date))
```

> File "C:/Users/tronc/PycharmProjects/oop_TEST/main.py", line 26
>      def dayIsWorkday(day):
>        ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

You may think that it's not useful, i think that too, but it's for a tutorial i'm trying to follow and i don't wanna go any further till i get what i done wrong

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: i posted it now

Comment: You shouldn't indent the code after your decorator.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no indentation for the function name in the next line after `@staticmethod`

```
>class Employee:
>   @staticmethod
>   def dayIsWorkday(day):
>       if day.weekday() == 5 or day.weekday() == 6:
>             return False
>       return True
>
>
>import datetime
>my_date = datetime.date(2018, 12, 5)
>
>print(Employee.dayIsWorkday(my_date))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess its an indentation error.
Check this

```
class Employee:
    @staticmethod
    def dayIsWorkday(day):
        if day.weekday() == 5 or day.weekday() == 6:
            return False
        return True


import datetime
my_date = datetime.date(2018, 12, 5)

print(Employee.dayIsWorkday(my_date))
```

Comment: oh nevermainf i forget the paranteses from the class method above so it wuldnt close corrrect thanks bye

Comment: I guess you have an error in another part of your code now.